# Excel: Looping through a row of cells and print each row

Tags: excel, loops, if-statement, while-loop, do-while

I want to print a rows of information onto another sheet.
the problem is that the number of rows will always be dynamic never static.

For example:

```
*A1 = 4
*B1 = Thomas 
*C1 = Apples

*A2 = 2
*B2 = Jerry
*C2 = Oranges

*A3 = 1
*B3 = Tiffany
*C3 = Strawberries
```

What i want is to print these rows along with some string...

so on Sheet 2 startign on A1

I want it to read 
    A1  "A quantity of " & A1 & " must be conumed by " & B1 & " product will be " & C1 & chr(10)
    "A quantity of 4 must be consumed by Thomas product will be Apples" (a new line after each row)

I don't know how to create a look which will do this so I dont' have to worry about number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you mean by print each row.

You can loop through all values in Column 'A' and concatenate the values in the next column 'D' like this:

```
Sub Macro1()
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Dim rRng As Range
    Set rRng = Range("A1:A" & LastRow)

    For Each cell In rRng.Cells
        cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = "A quantity of " & cell.Value & " must be consumed by " & cell.Offset(0, 1).Value & " product will be " & cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
    Next
End Sub
```

---

Results looks like this:

[image]

---

***EDIT***

Since you mentioned a new line character, I'll assume you want all the text in one cell for some reason.  Try this:

```
Sub Macro1()
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Dim rRng As Range
    Set rRng = Range("A1:A" & LastRow)

    Dim result As Range
    Set result = Range("D1")

    result.Value = ""

    For Each cell In rRng.Cells
        result.Value = Range("D1").Value & "A quantity of " & cell.Value & " must be consumed by " & cell.Offset(0, 1).Value & " product will be " & cell.Offset(0, 2).Value & Chr(10)
    Next
End Sub
```

The results look like this now:

[image]

Comment: See edit for placing text into one cell with carriage return.